# PHP-MYSQL Display different colors according to a deadline

Tags: php, mysql, date, time, colors

How can I display a different div background color according to a deadline established into a mysql database data ?

i.e.
Mysql date: 10-10-2012

`display background-color: #FF9999` if today is from "before" to 1-10-2012
`display background-color: #FF0000` if today is from 1-10-2012 to 10-10-2012
`display background-color: #FFFFFF` if today is from 10-10-2012 to "after"

thanks

Comment: showing more code could help someone who can help you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

E.g. (untested):

define in your stylesheets:

```
.before { background-color: #FF9999; } 
.current { background-color: #FF0000; } 
.after { background-color: #FFFFFF; }
```

in your php:

```
$iNow = time();
$iDeadline = strtotime($sMySqlDate);
$iAfter = strtotime('+1 day', $iDeadline);
$iBefore = strtotime('-10 days', $iDeadline);
$sClass = ($iNow >= $iAfter ? 'after' : ($iNow < $iBefore ? 'before' : 'current'));
echo '<div class="' . $sClass . '">...</div>';
```

=== UPDATE ===

Reading a timestamp from a mysql database:

```
$sSql = "SELECT `closedate` FROM `table`";
$rResult = mysql_query($sSql);
if (!$rResult) {
    echo "Could not successfully run query ($sSql) from DB: " . mysql_error();
    exit;
}

$aRow = mysql_fetch_assoc($rResult);
$sMySqlDate = $aRow['closedate'];
mysql_free_result($rResult);
```

Comment: Great ! how can I "retrieve" the data from the MySQL database ($sMySqlDate or $iDeadline)?

Comment: Can you give me your database structure first (tablename and columns)?

Comment: My table is: ID - listname - opendate - closedate

Answer (score 0):

Get the timestamp of current date and timestamp of date from a database and then compare them. Use strtotime function.

Example:

```php
$date1 = strtotime('01-07-2012');
$date2 = strtotime('01-02-2009');

if($date1 > $date2) echo 'The first date was before second one.';
```

Comment: You can simply insert 4 blanks (space bar) at the beginning of the line and the whole line will be parsed as <code><pre>. If I'm not wrong there should be also one empty new line before it.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a combination of [`date()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.date.php) and [`strtotime()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php). In my example I'm assuming you have the date in a some sort of SQL query result, e.g. `$result['date']` and it is rather `2012-10-10` than `10-10-2012`.

```
$date = strtotime($result['date']);
$before = strtotime('2012-01-01');
$after = strtotime('2012-12-31');

$today = strtotime(date(Y-m-d));

if($today >= $before && $today < strtotime('2012-10-01')){
    echo 'display background-color: #FF9999';
}
elseif($today >= strtotime('2012-10-01') && $today <= strtotime('2012-10-10')){
    echo 'display background-color: #FF0000';
}
elseif($today > strtotime('2012-10-10') && $today <= $after){
    echo 'display background-color: #FFFFFF';
}
```